# Query in mysql works but when assigned to a variable in php doesn't give the result

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

I have the following query written in mysql. It works properly in mysql but when I assign it to the variable in php and try to run it ,it gives an error -  "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected identifier "IPRANDPATENTS"". How am I supposed to run this query in php successfully?

```
    <table align="center">
        <tr>
            <th>RollNo</th>
            <th>IPRANDPATENTS</th>
            <th>COMPUTERNETWORKS</th>
            <th>DATAWAREHOUSINGANDMINING</th>
            <th>DESIGNANDANALYSISOFALGORITHMS</th>
            <th>SOFTWARETESTINGMETHODOLOGIES</th>
            <th>NETWORKPROGRAMMINGLAB</th>
            <th>DATAWAREHOUSINGANDMININGLAB</th>
            <th>SOFTWARETESTINGLAB</th>
            <th>INTERNETOFTHINGS</th>
        </tr>

    <?php
        
        $sql= "SELECT rollnum, 
max((case when subject='IPRANDPATENTS' then gradea end)) as `IPRANDPATENTS`,
max((case when subject='COMPUTERNETWORKS' then gradea end)) as `COMPUTERNETWORKS`, 
max((case when subject='DATAWAREHOUSINGANDMINING' then gradea end)) as `DATAWAREHOUSINGANDMINING`, 
max((case when subject='DESIGNANDANALYSISOFALGORITHMS' then gradea end)) as `DESIGNANDANALYSISOFALGORITHMS`,
max((case when subject='SOFTWARETESTINGMETHODOLOGIES' then gradea end)) as `SOFTWARETESTINGMETHODOLOGIES`,
max((case when subject='NETWORKPROGRAMMINGLAB' then gradea end)) as `NETWORKPROGRAMMINGLAB`,
max((case when subject='DATAWAREHOUSINGANDMININGLAB' then gradea end)) as `DATAWAREHOUSINGANDMININGLAB`,
max((case when subject='SOFTWARETESTINGLAB' then gradea end)) as `SOFTWARETESTINGLAB`,
max((case when subject='INTERNETOFTHINGS' then gradea end)) as `INTERNETOFTHINGS`
from ocse4year group by rollnum;
";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    

        $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        if ($resultCheck > 0)
            {
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
                {
                    echo "<tr><td>". $row["rollnum"] . 
                    "</td><td>" . $row["IPRANDPATENTS"] . 
                    "</td><td>" . $row["COMPUTERNETWORKS"] . 
                    "</td><td>" . $row["DATAWAREHOUSINGANDMINING"] . 
                    "</td><td>" . $row["DESIGNANDANALYSISOFALGORITHMS"] . 
                    "</td><td>" . $row["SOFTWARETESTINGMETHODOLOGIES"] . 
                    "</td><td>" . $row["NETWORKPROGRAMMINGLAB"] .
                    "</td><td>" . $row["DATAWAREHOUSINGANDMININGLAB"] .  
                    "</td><td>" . $row["SOFTWARETESTINGLAB"] . 
                    "</td><td>" . $row["INTERNETOFTHINGS"] . 
                    "</td></tr>";
                }
            echo "</table>";
            }

        else{
        echo "0 result";
    }
    
    $conn-> close();
    ?>

</table>
```

[image]

Comment: Double quote chars in MySQL are used for JSON paths/values, not for object names quoting. Replace with backticks.

Comment: double quotes causing you problem, use backtick or single quotes or leave it without quotes.

Comment: I replaced it with backticks but guess what, I got empty tables

Comment: Change `"IPRANDPATENTS"` to `IPRANDPATENTS`

Comment: Doesnt work....

Comment: To get errors out of PHP even in a LIVE environment add these 4 lines to the top of any `MYSQLI_` based script you want to debug 
`ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);`. 
This will force any `MYSQLI_` errors to generate an Exception that you can see on the browser as well as normal PHP errors.

Answer (score -2):

Please replace the alias names with `'` instead.

So **"IPRANDPATENTS"** would be **'IPRANDPATENTS'** - the issue is that you are breaking out of the string by using `"` inside a string declared with `"`. PHP thinks that the string has ended, that's why it didn't expect `IPRANDPATENTS`.

Comment: Yes I did. Yet There seems to be some problem

Comment: Does it print _0 result_? Can you try printing something inside the while-loop.

Comment: I tried. It prints the roll numbers but not the result

Comment: This would only be needed if the variables were interpolated in the string. It doesn't make a difference when concatenating.